# Not able to set proper view while streaming video call

Tags: ios, video, pjsip, xcode10.1

I'm using PJSIP library for video call and video is streaming properly and im trying to show video preview with the help of window id that I get from pjsua_vid_win_info() but im not getting a proper view while adding it as such.

```
var previewInfo = pjsua_vid_win_info()
pjsua_vid_win_get_info(Int32(windowId), &previewInfo)
let streamView = Unmanaged<UIView>.fromOpaque(previewInfo.hwnd.info.ios.window).takeUnretainedValue()
streamView.frame.size.width = view.frame.width
streamView.frame.size.height = view.frame.height
streamView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
view.isHidden = false
view.addSubview(streamView)
```

Tried changing resolution from 288*352, 120*160, 240*320

===== EDITED =======
I'm calling this func on registering sip account and also on change media state:

```
void setup_video_codec_params(void)
{
    //Set Video Codec Parameters before this starts transmitting
    pjsua_codec_info vid_codec_ids[32];
    unsigned int vid_codec_count=PJ_ARRAY_SIZE(vid_codec_ids);

    pjsua_vid_enum_codecs(vid_codec_ids, &vid_codec_count);

    //For every codec
    for(int i=0;i<vid_codec_count; i++){
        pjmedia_vid_codec_param codec_param;
        pjsua_vid_codec_get_param(&vid_codec_ids[i].codec_id, &codec_param);
        codec_param.ignore_fmtp = PJ_TRUE;

        codec_param.enc_fmt.det.vid.size.w = 1280;
        codec_param.enc_fmt.det.vid.size.h = 720;
        codec_param.dec_fmt.det.vid.size.w = 1280;
        codec_param.dec_fmt.det.vid.size.h = 720;
        pj_status_t status_codec_set_params = pjsua_vid_codec_set_param(&(vid_codec_ids[i].codec_id), &codec_param);

        if(status_codec_set_params != PJ_SUCCESS)
        {
            NSLog(@"pjsua_vid_codec_set_param Failed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect when tried changing resolution? I'm using **pjmedia_vid_codec_param()**  (openh264) for video preview.

Comment: Please find edited question @SonPham